# Import Boolean from another Class

Tags: java, variables, while-loop, minecraft, spigot

I have a `DataHolders` class.
It contains:

```
public static boolean hit;
```

In my other class theres:

```
public void onHit(ProjectileHitEvent event) {
    if (event.getHitEntity() != null || event.getHitBlock() != null) {
        DataHolders.hit = true;
    }
}
```

`ProjectileHitEvent` gets triggered when a Player **hits** something with a Projectile (Arrow)

In my last class:

```
public void onLaunch(ProjectileLaunchEvent event) {
    while (!DataHolders.hit) {
        //..............
    }
}
```

`ProjectileLaunchEvent` gets triggered when a Player **launches** the Projectile (Arrow)

I want to do something while the Projectile (Arrow) is in the air (`ProjectileLaunchEvent` triggered but `ProjectileHitEvent` not).
But when the Arrow hits something (`ProjectileHitEvent` gets triggered and `boolean hit` becomes `true`) the loop should stop but the while loop goes on. I've already tested if `ProjectileHitEvent` really gets triggered, it works but the loop doesn't.

Comment: Try using AtomicBoolean or volatile

Comment: It appears to me that method `onHit` and method `onLaunch` run in different threads. You should check if that is the case.

Comment: Nope doesnt work

Comment: Your code does not show where you set `DataHolders.hit` to `false`

Comment: I forgot but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

**check if `DataHolders.hit` is true/false.**

```
public void onLaunch(ProjectileLaunchEvent event) {
    while (!DataHolders.hit) {
        System.out.println(DataHolders.hit);
        //..............
    }
}
```

**If true**

You should focus on setting `DataHolders.hit` properly

**If false**

Print the value before/after setting the value

```
public void onHit(ProjectileHitEvent event) {
    if (event.getHitEntity() != null || event.getHitBlock() != null) {
        System.out.println(DataHolders.hit);
        DataHolders.hit = true;
        System.out.println(DataHolders.hit);
    }
}
```

If the latter output is `true` then there is a problem with the class where `public static boolean hit;` exists.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work